# Проблема при внедрении браузера Chromium (cef4delphi) в приложение на Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, chromium

Нашёл статью по установке браузера Chromium в Delphi 10.3, а именно вот ссылка на неё http://www.proghouse.ru/programming/146-chromium-delphi

Проблема на этапе копирования файлов CEF в папку с проектом, а именно вылетает CEF binaries missing не смотря на то что нужные файлы я в папку с проектом положил. Даже положил файлы проекта специально поближе к корню диска C а именно C:\delphiProjects\2\ - это пака проекта. В ней создаётся папка Win32 а в ней ещё Debug так вот я эти файлов от CEF положил уже и в папку с проектом и в Win32 и в Debug Delphi всё равно описанной выше ошибкой "...missing" ругается на список файлов.

Для тех кто будет отвечать на вопрос - он именно про cef4delphi и именно про установку на Delphi 10.3 а не про старую версию cef3, если кому то нужно будет именно cef3 устанавливать, я делал по вот это статье - https://blog.ivru.net/?id=211 но версия браузера достаточно старая, youTube например будет открываться с проблемами. Так что меня интересует именно cef4delphi.

Что я делаю не так и в какую папку всё же нужно положить эти файлы, потому что явно не во все три папки жеж их надо? Архив файлов CEF(не файлов cef4delphi) я скачал с названием: cef_binary_87.1.12+g03f9336+chromium-87.0.4280.88_windows32.tar

Comment: а условие из статьи `Версии CEF и браузера Chromium и версии, указанные в CEF4Delphi должны совпадать с теми, что указаны в файле uCEFApplicationCore.pas` соблюдено? p.s. файлы нужны только рядом со своим .exe, ни к исходникам, ни в промежуточные папки их кидать не надо

Comment: Да, версия CEF подходит, а именно скачена последняя допустимая версия CEF для скаченной версии cef4delphi :( Уже написал что вообще в все возможные папки положил библиотеки CEF - результат всё тот же. Есть мысли что возможно какие то права Windows нужно выставить чтобы проект эти файлы увидел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если делали по статье что привели по первой ссылке и если Вы пробуете на demo проектах из тех же скаченных файлов CEF, возможно Ваш проект компилируется не в папку с файлами проекта(в том числе в указанные Вами папки Win32 и Debug) а в папку C:\Bin\ так что проверьте наличие этой папки на Вашем диске C, и наличие в C:\Bin\ скомпилированного файла проекта. Если он там просто добавьте в C:\Bin\ библиотеки от CEF и проект должен запуститься. В моём случаи именно в C:\Bin\ проходила компиляция демо-проектов.

Comment: Да, именно в этом была проблема. Положил файлы CEF в C:\Big\и проект в студии сразу откомпилировался без ошибок и запустился.